# What's the difference between 'another' and 'second'?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between another and second?

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary definitions of the two words? They are only synonyms in one particular circumstance.

Comment: If you're Polish, have you tried looking in Wikisłownik? [The page for "another"](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/another) defines it as "jeszcze jeden, następny, inny, kolejny," whereas [the page for "second"](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/second) defines it as "drugi." I don't know Polish very well, but I think those definitions seem pretty accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If I am in a bar with a friend and we have had one beer my friend might say "Do you want a second one?" as an offer to buy a round. He could also say "Do you want another one?" But after the second one I can't say "Would you like a second one?" because we've already had two. I could say "Would you like a third one?" but I'm more likely to say "Do you want another one?". After the third one we would only say "another" because we'd start to lose count!

The point is that "another" is the same as "one more" no matter how many have gone before (so long as at least one has gone before) but "second" only applies to the one after the first. You could have laid a hundred bricks so far today but the one hundred and first is still "another" brick.